# java - how to implement libGDX checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, libgdx, listener

I never used the checkbox of libGDX before, and I don't know how to start implementing it in a proper way to Android.
I want to change some things when the checkbox is set to true and change other things when it is set to false. Do I need to make `if (checkbox.isChecked()) {...} else{...}` at `render()`? or I need to add a `ChangeListener` to my checkBox? or a `InputListener`? or none of these? or all of these? (just kidding in the last question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you want the checkbox to do. Most times you will want to use a listener to handle any sort of user input.

For example, if you want to show extra forms to a user when the check a box you only want to create / delete those forms once (on the corresponding check / uncheck actions).

Here is an official example of use for a checkbox listener:

```
checkBox.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(checkBox.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Source: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java (Good for all types of UI elements in libgdx)

Comment: Do I need to `@Override` the `changed()` method of `ChangeListener`?

Comment: Yes you can add the `@Override` annotation if you want.